# how to get days out of date using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, date-arithmetic

I have a table which contains dates and number of orders.

I want to show the number of orders per day of the week. Like for example only the orders for monday from the past 120 days.

I have this sql-string to constract data per day for the last 120 days, but these are every day. I only want these per day.

```
select 
  date_format(google_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as dateday, 
  google_orders as total 
from   
  site_google 
where date_sub(curdate(), interval 120 day) <= google_date 
group by dateday
```

is this possible to show only data for monday, and one for tuesday, wednesday etc.?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: i'm using mysql 5.0.95

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`DAYOFWEEK() function`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) to get every monday. Also you want to use an aggregate function or remove the `group by`.

```
select 
   date(google_date) as dateday, 
   sum(google_orders) as total 
from site_google 
where 
date_sub(curdate(), interval 120 day) <= google_date 
and dayofweek(date(google_date)) = 2
group by dateday
```